# How to read Json data in Excel vba?

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

Do you know how can I take "actualEnd values" from Json file to my Excel VBA? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtOQD.png)

I already have this vba code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w34dh.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please do not post code as a screenshot. Reading [ask] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of code and instead include the relevant snippets within the question.